# Validation error during model generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get the following error when generating a model:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: MvcDemo.Models.Employee: : EntityType 'Employee' has no key defined.

How would I solve this?

```
[Table("tblEmployee")] 
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

Error:

```
Line 15:  {
Line 16:    EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
Line 17:    Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmpID == id);
Line 18:             
Line 19:    return View(employee);
```

Comment: So, which part of _'Employee' has no key defined_ seems to be confusing?

Answer (score 6):

Either change your Primary Key from `EmpId` to `Id` or add an annotation to your current key:

```
[Key]
public int EmpID { get; set; }
```

I've made assumptions that this is Entity Framework Code First btw...

Making one of these changes will tell EF to automatically create your key as an identity column.